# Need help adding a button in the node editor using gpu or bgl

Tags: python, gpu

what i have sofa just lets me draw a rectangle in the viewport,
need a button in node editor thanks

````
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

vertices = (
    (100, 100), (300, 100),
    (100, 200), (300, 200))

indices = (
    (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)


def draw():
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')```
````

Comment: Editor windows are composed of several region and how you add a button depends on which region you want to add it to.  For instance, if you want it in the header you would add a menu entry; if you wanted it in the sidebar; you would add a panel to the side bar and place the button in the panel; et cetera.  But you don't use gpu or bgl for buttons.  Which part of the editor do you want the button in and what do you want it for?

Comment: i need buttons that are always visible in the node editor without first pressing N key, it seems the onlyway to do that is using GPU module

Comment: You can stick them in the header; the bar across the top or bottom that has the menus. Will that serve your purpose?